# flutter build apk -->FAILURE: Build failed with an exception

Tags: flutter

`flutter build apk
Flutter assets will be downloaded from https://storage.flutter-io.cn. Make sure you trust this source!

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':webview_flutter_android:parseReleaseLocalResources'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':webview_flutter_android:androidApis'.
> Failed to transform android.jar to match attributes {artifactType=android-platform-attr, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.usage=java-runtime}.
> > Execution failed for PlatformAttrTransform: C:\Users\huihao\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-32\android.jar.
> > C:\Users\huihao\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-32\android.jar

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.`

hlep me,hlep me,hlep me，hlep me，hlep me

Comment: Your question is really unclear can you help me understand what are you trying to do here?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.